# Install plugin generatePom produces error

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

We pre-package a dependency with the application,and use Maven install plugin to inject into the classpath.

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>artifactXXX</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactXXX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In the install:

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>install-artifactXXX</id>
    <phase>install</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>install-file</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <groupId>artifactXXX</groupId>
      <artifactId>artifactXXX</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <file>${basedir}/jars/artifactXXX.jar</file>
      <generatePom>true</generatePom>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

However, during `clean install` Maven still tries to download the POM for the dependent JAR from Artifactory and produces a POM not found error.
What is to be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependency resolution happens before `<build>` proccessing. So, at the time Maven processes the `<dependencies>` section the artifact hasn't been installed yet.

You have to perform `install:install-file` manually on the command line at least once before your POM build (and you have to be aware of that, if using a `-SNAPSHOT` version, the dependency installed by the previous build is used in the current build).

Furthermore, such a configuration doesn't comply with the declarative nature of Maven POMs. It's like trying to grow a plant from seeds of the plant that is to be grown.